# Product Topology and Box Topology

Tags: general-topology

Hello I have some questions. The first one, in the process of constructing the product topology why is it true that: $ \displaystyle\bigcap^n_{i=0} p^{-1}(G_{i_{k}}) = {\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} G_{i}}$? And also, what is the deeper connection between the product and the box topology? 
Thank you

Comment: The equation does not make sense: finite intersection (what are $n$ and the $i_k$ indices?) vs infinite product.

Answer (score 2):

What is true is $$\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty p_i^{-1}[G_i] = \prod_{i=0}^\infty G_i$$

because $f$ is in the left hand side iff $$\forall i: f \in p_i^{-1}[G_i] \text { iff } \forall i: f(i) \in G_i$$

which is exactly the condition for being in the right hand product.

There is no "deeper connection": the product topology is just coarser (smaller) than the box topology on $\prod_{i=0}^\infty X_i$.